# How to organise test files for unit testing in Python with sub folders

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing

I was wondering how I can setup my directory structure to enable importing any python file from `project` in the `tests` directory to test it?

Currently I'm getting a Module not found error when trying to import a class from `some_file.py` in `some_file_tests.py`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\Documents\GitHub\Project\tests\util\some_file_test.py", line 3, in <module>
    from project.util.some_file import SomeFile
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project'
```

`tests/util.some_file_test.py`

```py
from project.util.some_file import SomeClass
```

Here is the directory structure

```
Project
 ┣ project
 ┃ ┣ util
 ┃ ┃ ┣ some_file.py
 ┃ ┃ ┗ __init__.py
 ┃ ┗ __init__.py
 ┣ tests
 ┃ ┣ util
 ┃ ┃ ┗ some_file_test.py
```

And here is an example of what the `__init__.py` files contain.

`project/__init__.py`

```py
from . import util
```

`project/util/__init__.py`

```py
from . import some_file
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some reasearch (thanks @gftea) I found that in each `__init__` file, doing `from . import ___` is unecessary and can be removed (for my use case anyways).

Then I created these files in the root folder:

`setup.py`

```py
from setuptools import setup
setup()
```

`setup.cfg`

```
[metadata]
name = <NAME>
version = 0.0.1
description = <DESCRIPTION>
long_description = file: README.md
long_description_content_type = text/markdown
url = <GITHUB REPOSITORY URL>
author = <AUTHOR(S)>
license = GPL-3.0
license_file = LICENSE
classifiers =
    License :: OSI Approved :: GNU General Public License v3 (GPLv3)
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3 :: Only
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3.8
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3.9
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3.10

[options]
packages = find:
install_requires =
    python-dotenv==0.19.2
    requests==2.27.1
python_requires = >=3.8
tests_require =
    pytest
    coverage

[options.packages.find]
exclude =
    tests*

[options.extras_require]
dev =
    black==22.1.0
    pylint==2.12.2
```

Afterwards I installed my package using `pip install -e .`

Then in the test python file I can do `from project.util.some_file import SomeClass`

Comment: in development phase, use `pip install -e .` which install your project in editable mode, so that you can debug and edit the code

Answer (score 2):

two ways

1. add the `project` path to PYTHONPATH environment variable before running test.
2. add the `project` path to sys.path programmatically in your test file before importing modules in project

```
import sys
sys.path.append("path/to/project")
from project.util.some_file import SomeClass
```

Comment: How would this work when there are multiple collaborators of the codebase? As each of our paths to the project may be different. Is there no way to do this generically, like with `__init__` files for example?

Comment: the proper way is to use setuptools or other 3rd-party tools to properly handling packaging for you, e.g. tox.  Python package handling is more than complex than usually new pythoner imagine. 
So for a quick solution, you can use this, see https://www.devdungeon.com/content/python-import-syspath-and-pythonpath-tutorial

Comment: I'm not looking for a quick solution sorry, I'm after an answer that works and is the intended way to set up testing for Python projects.

Comment: then you need to have setuptools for your project, see https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/setuptools.html. Or just use tox to create project, see https://tox.wiki/en/latest/install.html. you will need to read through the document